# How to access node on server hosting

Tags: node.js

Need some help for newbie like me,
I was upload my node js project to server hosting vps using sentora.
And now i dont understand to running my project.

in my local computer running node just type command

> node server.js

and i can access in browser localhost:8080

My question is how running node js in server hosting ?

Comment: Access your server's command line and start it?

Comment: Have you consulted the documentation?

Comment: [Sentora Doc](http://docs.sentora.org/)

Comment: i cant find command line in my sentora admin panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Sentora, but a quick look at their forum shows that Sentora was [not built](http://forums.sentora.org/showthread.php?tid=1418&pid=9157&highlight=nodejs#pid9157) to [handle Node.js](http://forums.sentora.org/showthread.php?tid=2875&pid=16822&highlight=nodejs#pid16822). It is meant for PHP servers.

You could try going for another hosting service that fully supports Node.js, such as Digital Ocean or Heroku. Digital Ocean also provides a fully configurable Ubuntu box where you can perform all kinds of CLI operations.

For persistent deployment, I advise using a tool like `forever` from NPM. It will keep your server alive even after you exit the ssh session with Ubuntu box.

To install `forever`, go to your Ubuntu box and type:

```
$ [sudo] npm install forever -g
```

Then go to your Node.js project directory and deploy server as follows:

```
$ cd /path/to/your/project
forever start app.js
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.
i can try upload my project on heroku.

Comment: Great! I see that you are a new user, so if this answer helped you, please consider upvoting it and marking it as accepted answer.

Comment: @Nivedit, I am trying to upload my node project on heroku, build success but not in browser.